# Execution of spoon task along with running instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, spoon

I have been working on functional testing in Android using Espresso. After adding it successfully I thought of creating reports for the test I added.

For reports I used spoon. Set it up correctly and ran it using the script containing the following command given here 
http://square.github.io/spoon/

**Query :** 
But my query was that is there any possibility  by which we can run this spoon task run through AndroidStudio menu option that runs functional tests.

Please let me know :

1. If it is possible at all or not ?
2. When possible, what to do for the configurations ?

Note : from command line gradle spoon task is working fine and creating reports

Thanks

Comment: Hey did you solve your prblem ?

Comment: I think I ended up using gradle commands only.